# Button.Template WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I`ve created big button which contains grid as below:

```
   <Button Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Command="{Binding ContinueWithoutScan}" BorderThickness="0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" 
                                       Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
                                       FontSize="25" Foreground="White"/>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Height="Auto" Width="70"  Kind="ChevronRight" Foreground="White"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

There is problem that only TextBlock inside Template is clickable. Does anyone know how do I make whole content clickable? I working with MVVM so I dont want make Grid.OnMouseEneter.

Is there option to do that of I have to use EventTriggers?

Comment: Try `<Grid Background="Transparent">`

Comment: You need to have Background set for the MouseOver to work. Try adding Background="Transparent" to the Grid in your ControlTemplate.

Comment: perfect thank You guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grid needs to have a Background other than the default `null` to receive input events. You may set a transparent background instead of null:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    ...
</Grid>
```